# How we acess System Note Search through PHP?

Tags: web-services, netsuite, php-toolkit

I have created a **System Note Search** which executes successfully. Now I'm trying to access this search results in php. I'm stuck with what type of object I use for implementing this search. Below is the code-

```
$service = new NetSuiteService();
$search = new needtoIdentify();
$search->savedSearchId = "897";  // SavedSearch ID.
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately System Notes are not part of Netsuite Web Services Supported Records. You might need to work around this by using suitescript either to passthrough the data through a Suitelet/Restlet or a scheduled script that saves the results of the System Notes in the file cabinet so you can pick it up with WebServices.

Comment: Now I'm implementing it by creating new employee search then comparing some fields and complete my implementation.